# cumulative calculated row in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge pandas df as below

```
Country  category brand quarter device countA  CountB  percentageA/B
XXX       A1       A2     Q2     PC    12       12       100
XXX       A1       A2     Q2     Tablet 2        4       50 
YYY       A4       A5     Q4     PC     50        50     100
YYY       A4       A5     Q4     Tablet  10       10      100
```

I need to add a row to the data which is the sum of above 2 data points

```
Country  category brand quarter device countA  CountB  percentage(A/B) 
XXX       A1       A2     Q2     PC    12       12       100 % 
XXX       A1       A2     Q2     Tablet 2        4       50 %
**XXX       A1       A2     Q2     PC + Tablet 14  16      87.5%**
YYY       A4       A5     Q4     PC     50        50     100
YYY       A4       A5     Q4     Tablet  10       12     83%
**YYY       A4       A5     Q4     PC+Tablet 60      62        96.7%**
```

Please find the structure of d 
So ideally there are few Brands in the category that only have one device

```
Country       category  brand    quarter         device
XXX           A1           A2       Q2         Tablet +PC
              A4          A5        Q2         Tablet+PC 
              A9          A10       Q2             PC
                          A11       Q1             PC
```

print(type(d))

Comment: We need more information. What have you tried? How are you calculating `percentA/B`? Look into `df.groupby('Country').sum()`

Comment: I tried exactly the same structure, but it gives me the output in a different format than needed df.groupby(['Country ','category','brand','quarter]).sum()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `groupby` `merge` and `concat` Also, you still never mentioned how `percentageA/B` is calculated

```
# groupby and apply with join to get devices
d = df.groupby(['Country','category','brand','quarter'])['device'].apply('+'.join)
# groupby with sum then merge the two groups together with reset_index
new = df.groupby(['Country','category','brand','quarter']).sum().merge(d, left_index=True, right_index=True).reset_index()
# concat original df with new
pd.concat([df,new], sort=False)

  Country category brand quarter     device  countA  CountB  percentageA/B
0     XXX       A1    A2      Q2         PC      12      12            100
1     XXX       A1    A2      Q2     Tablet       2       4             50
2     YYY       A4    A5      Q4         PC      50      50            100
3     YYY       A4    A5      Q4     Tablet      10      10            100
0     XXX       A1    A2      Q2  PC+Tablet      14      16            150
1     YYY       A4    A5      Q4  PC+Tablet      60      60            200
```

or you can try:

```
# groupby and apply with join to get devices
d = df.groupby(['Country','category','brand','quarter'])['device'].apply('+'.join).to_frame().reset_index()
# groupby with sum then merge the two groups together with reset_index
new = df.groupby(['Country','category','brand','quarter'], as_index=False).sum().merge(d, on=['Country','category','brand','quarter'])
# concat original df with new
final_df = pd.concat([df,new], sort=False)
final_df['percentageA/B'] = final_df['countA'] / final_df['CountB'] * 100
```

Comment: The merge gives an error can not merge DataFrame with an instance of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: @NehaSharma what version of pandas are you using because it works fine in .24.1; however, try changing `d` to `d.to_frame()`

Comment: Thanks for the patience, Chris. I am using pandas: 0.23.4. The above suggested still gives the same error

Comment: Can you do `print(d.head(10))` and `print(type(d))` and paste the results in your question so I can see what it looks like and add the code you are trying.

Comment: Here from the documentation `"Support for merging named Series objects was added in version 0.24.0"` Looks like you will need to upgrade pandas in order for the above code to work. If you are interested in upgrading pandas please read the [release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/index.html) so you know how it will impact previous projects.

Comment: thanks after a while of struggling this works. However you were right in asking about how the percentage is calculated, it counts A col / Count B col. It is only where the results are not correct. It is sum whereas I want them to a computed percentage

Comment: `final_df = pd.concat([df,new], sort=False);final_df['percentageA/B'] = final_df['countA'] / final_df['CountB'] * 100`

Comment: that was fine i could change it , Have accepted your answer , Thank you it works smooth now